# Salesforce REST API Time-out after 4 callouts

Tags: rest-api, webservices, integration, c#, timeout

Good day.

I really need help on this issue. I have tries every possible option here.
I use the Salesforce REST API using C#.
The works 100% fine but after a couple of calls out to SF i keep on getting the error "The operation has timed out"

Comment: Have you tried using setTimeout() method to increase your timeout limit ?

Comment: yes, I have tried to this set to the maximum(120 Second).

Comment: what si the end point u r calling?

Answer (score 1):

- You can set REST API call-out time to maximum 120 second. If your  C# application is unable to process request in 120 seconds then you will have to optimize  C# webservice. Default timeout is 10 seconds.

  > Sample:

  ```
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
  req.setEndpoint(endpoint_url);
  req.setMethod('GET');
  req.setTimeout(120000);
  ```

  - I will recommed to use (Asynchronous) Apex Batch if you are making  large number of callouts. You won't be able to do it synchronously.